# A Huge Database: Picking the right schema and data model

Tags: database-design, schema, scalability

We want to store some genomic variant data but there are some problems, more important ones like problem of the data's immense size and variability.

1) Variant data can be huge. For example, a single individuals variant data could feasibly some day require a million rows of data in a table, or require of a gigabyte of raw storage on disk. Multiply this over several thousand individuals, and you could potentially end up with terabytes worth of information that you need to make sense of.

2) Each client and/or system we integrate with, will expose or want to see data slightly differently depending on their needs and use cases. This can potentially lead to hundreds of fields that we might need to store, all of which might need to be in different configurations based on the clients needs. So this variant data model will need to keep this in mind in order to remain easy to use, expandable and most importantly, scalable in the long term.

What do you think is better for such a problem? We were thining of having some coulmns in each table that point to an external database or even a file, where we save the huge BLOB data?

Comment: It will depend entirely on how you plan to use the data.  Off-row storage would work as long as you will never filter or manipulate that off-row data.  As soon as you filter on it, you are doing a table scan which requires every row to be retrieved.

Comment: crossposted http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/147770/a-huge-database-picking-the-right-schema-and-data-model

Comment: Presumably Genome data is all sequences of GATTACA, which should be amenable to transformation into a common format, or am I missing something?

Comment: @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells : nop, basically information like this: http://dgvbeta.tcag.ca/dgv/app/chromosome?ref=NCBI36/hg18

Comment: So it's higher level than gene sequences?

Comment: Wnat data do these have in common that you want to examine across all the sources?

Comment: @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells : they may or may not have many things in common. Its like one patinent has one million rows of data about his genes..and let's say we will have six thousand patients...

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to store/analyze? The amino acids can only be paired with their analog. However, the sequence of these amino acids can vary slightly, within the same location within the chromosome and still be considered a gene (though it's a mutation). What they all have in common is the pairing of A-T C-G

Comment: @bdoat Regarding the link: Is that the project that you're working on, or is this something that you're trying to do in parallel to that?

Comment: Another point which needs clarification is what you mean with *"data's immense size and **variability**."* Leaving the immense size aside for the moment, what do you mean with *variabilty*? Do the data come from various sources in various formats?

Comment: CAn I suggest that it would be far better to hire the appropriate database experts to do a database design like this than to ask question on the Internet. This is a complex database problme and requires someone with a minimum of ten years of database design experience and some of it on large systems to get a workable design. This is not the kind of database that application programmers have any business designing.

Answer (score 1):

I have not experience such scenario but based on my present knowledge I would suggest you have a table which contains union of all the column which any client can need e.g. say client A wants  column 1 and 2 and client 2 wants column 2 and 3 and you have only these two clients then create a table with column 1,2 and 3 and in case of client 1 keep column 3 as null and in case of client 2 keep column 2 as null. Once you are done with this create view for each client e.g.create View A, it should have column 1,2 and will be used in case of client A similarly create view for each client.

Also I would suggest to keep data in table only and not separatly on disc as it create sync issue.

Answer (score 0):

Structure? !

If the data is just a zillion-character string with 4 possible letters and store each in a file.

If you have meta data associated with the string, how big will that be?  How should that be structured in a relational database table?

There are only 4 letters, correct?  That means 2 bits suffice for each letter.  Design an encoding so you can store 4 letters per byte.  Then experiment with zip and other compression tools.

Whether to put the string (of letters or 2-bit codes) into a LONGTEXT/LONGBLOB, or put it into a file -- that question comes up often with respect to "should I store my images in a table or a file".  The answer is pretty much the same:

- table -> referential integrity (less likely to lose string vs meta data)
- file -> might be easier for other tools to access